# Laravel how to pass validation errors back to remote modal window

Tags: ajax, laravel, bootstrap-dialog

After validation, I lose the Session/messagebag $error data in my modal. I guess this is because I am loading my edit form *attendee/edit* into the modal body from a link so the $error data gets sent to the page that calls up the modal but not the modal body. When I turn off the modal and just have it load the page *attendee/edit* directly, the validation errors show up fine. Is there a way to pass my $error variable to my edit form displayed in the modal body?

I would prefer using AJAX because it seems in my current implementation I need to reload the modal so it pops out/in. But I am not sure how to transfer the $error messagebag object from the edit form/Session data to the modal that way either. I am wondering if there is a way to use this method [stackoverflow.com/questions/25103743/laravel-4-validation-in-bootstrap-modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103743/laravel-4-validation-in-bootstrap-modal) to fill in the $error messagebag.

**Main View**

```
    <td>{{link_to_route('attendee.edit','',array($attendee->id), array(
            'class'=>'edit-attendee btn btn-info btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-pencil',
            'data-title' => 'Edit Attendee'))}} 
    </td>
```

**JQuery call to BootstrapDialog**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn.edit-attendee').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: $(this).data('title'),
            message: $('<div></div>').load(url),
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Update',
                action: function(dialogRef) {
                    $('form').submit();
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

**attendee/edit view**

```
{{ Form::model($attendee, array('class'=>'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('attendee.update', $attendee->id))) }}
        <div class="form-group {{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}}">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label", for="first_name">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                {{ Form::text('first_name', null , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            </div>
          {{ $errors->first('first_name', '<span class="help-inline">:message</span>')}}
        </div>

      <div class="form-group {{{ $errors->has('special_care') ? 'has-error' : '' }}}">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label", for="special_care">Special Care</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                {{ Form::text('special_care', null , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            </div>
            {{ $errors->first('age', '<span class="help-inline">:message</span>')}}
        </div>
        {{Form::submit()}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function update($id)
    {
        $attendee = Attendee::findOrFail($id);



  $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Attendee::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $attendee->update($data);

    return Redirect::route('attendees.index');
}
```

After I edit the form I want to return to the modal window to display validation errors but the $errors do not get passed to the modal.

Comment: If you have multiple forms on a single page, ->withErrors($validator, 'update'); and <?php echo $errors->update->first('fieldname'); ?>

Comment: I just have one form.

Answer (score 1):

**Named Error Bags**

If you have multiple forms on a single page, you may wish to name the `MessageBag` of errors. This will allow you to retrieve the error messages for a specific form. Simply pass a name as the second argument to `withErrors`:

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator, 'update')->withInput();
```

You may then access the named `MessageBag` instance from the `$errors` variable:

```
<?php echo $errors->update->first('fieldName'); ?>
```

Comment: I just have one form.